# How to find an element in a csv file and edit the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to create a program using kivy that takes in an input, checks if the value is inside the csv, and add hours based on that person's position.

Right now i'm trying to figure out how to check if an input is in a csv file, but i'm getting nothing.

(I just need help with the logic/method)

(I just starting coding like a month ago with a little experience prior so i'm kind of lost)

I tried iterating through rows and going through each field in the row to check the input. I run it, but I get nothing. Please Helppp. Thanks in advance.

```
def sign_in(self, text_input):
    self.text_input = text_input
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
        t = list(reader)
        i = 0
        for x in t:
            i += 1
            for field in x:
                if self.text_input == field:
                    if x[0] == "Vice President":
                        a = x[6]
                        a = 3.5 + int(a)
                        x[6] = a
                        fp.write(t[i])
                        self.signin()
                    else:
                        self.fk()
        else:
            self.noUser()
    fp.close()
```

**csv file**

position,name,school,grade,email,telephone #, hours

Vice President, John Park, High School, 11, burger@gmail.com, 1234567890, 0

The csv file is supposed to change with added hours in that row

Comment: `t = list(reader)
        i = 0
        for x in reader:` but `reader` has already been consumed. Use `t` instead in iteration

Comment: Thank You. I did that but still does not work with "John Park" as the input.

Comment: so is the input the person's name?

Comment: Yes, it asks for the full name for the input

Comment: You open the file in read mode and assign it to fp. Then later you execute fp.write(). I think that doesn't work, does it? I'd rather add another with clause the same way you already have it, after t=list(..), so opening the file once again, after it has been closed. this way you wouldn't have to call fp.close() neither. But this way, you would have to output all records, also the unchanged ones. In a csv you can't just write one line anyways, since the lenght of the line might change (e.g. if a changes from 1 to 4.5, you need two extra chars for that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to edit the csv file by searching a name, I would use the header as the placeholder for values, that way you aren't relying on position:

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    # get the headers out first, which is the first line
    headers = next(reader)

    for line in reader:
        # this will make a dictionary with the header values as
        # keys and the line entries as values
        # use l.strip to avoid the spaces following commas
        entry = dict(zip(headers, (l.strip() for l in line)))

        # use key access, it makes the code a bit more readable
        if entry['name'] == text_input.strip(): # strip leading and trailing whitespace
            print(line)
```

The `dict(zip(header, line))` isn't faster than just using `line[0] == text_input`, but if you are attempting to manipulate multiple values, I think the explicit-ness is a little nicer. That's more a style thing, though, and could be debated depending on your use case.

Now, the bigger problem is that you are attempting to call `fp.write` on a file opened with read-only access:

```py
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    fh.write('a')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

To get around this, you could write the new content to a new file, then when that's complete, overwrite the existing file:

```py
import os

with open('test.csv') as infile,
     open('new.csv', 'w') as outfile:
     for line in infile:
         # do things
         outfile.write(line)

# then when the method is complete
# move test.csv to new.csv, which overwrites the file
os.replace('new.csv', 'test.csv')
```

Comment: Thank You!! is the first section supposed to print the row? Its not printing anything.

Comment: @John it was the spaces following the commas, see newest edit

Comment: Do you know how to update test.csv? I added 3.5 to line[6] for test.csv, but when I try to write the lines to new.csv, its copies the original test.csv with nothing changed.

Comment: also im getting access denied to overwrite